# Woocommerce changing labels for Products in backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have changed the labels for products in woocommerce backend. I have used the `woocommerce_register_post_type_product` filter to update the product post labels.

Now I want to change the label for "Sort Product" filter to "Sort Courses".

Also I want to hide Product Data drop down which shows up when I edit the product.

Comment: What you want is clear, but what have you done to try to solve the problem? Any research?

Comment: I have used the woocommerce_register_post_type_product filter to update the product post labels. But I am not able to update other details.

Comment: Please add screenshots or code reference of what do you mean by "Sort Product" and "Product Data"