# Change the text of a label in a WP ecommerce site to something custom

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the text (for Quantity) showing up when I do select some options on a variable product in a Woocommerce site. To be more specific, I have some variable products that "Quantity" only appears when you choose the color, size etc of the product. So, all I want to do is change the label for Quantity and make it for example something like "Well, how many of them ?" and so on. Ideally, I would like the change to be permanent and independent from future updates. That's the label created:

```
<label class="label-quantity">quantity</label>
```

So, I have found that woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php is the file used to display all the information for a variable product.
Plus, this label is assigned via jquery, that's obvious but there is a call in line 78 to function `<?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>` and that leads me to some core files. Anyway, I have been struggling to change the label for quite some hours now but hadn't any luck.

Any advice/help/tip would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651496/woocommerce-changing-labels-for-products-in-backend

Comment: you can create your own variable.php in your theme folder...   to overwrite the core templates...

Comment: Could you give me some more directions on this ? What am I supposed to put in the variable.php file ? All these stuff are pretty new for me :/